# SQL Column search.. then use that as table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fairly rusty in my SQL.. what I am looking for is to start by searching all my tables for a given column

```
SELECT @myTables = TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%myColumn%'
```

Then I would like to use the results and run a search like so for every record

```
select * from @myTables[0]
select * from @myTables[1]
```

....

and so on.. I hope I am clear in describing what I am looking for.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `insert into @myTables` instead of `SELECT @myTables =`, then use a dynamic sql to get your data.

Comment: Are  you looking for single statement, a stored procedure or are you looking for more of a way to generate a sql query to search for data? Do you expect select the same number of fields in each table?

Comment: You basically just want something like `SELECT @myTables = COALESCE(@myTables, '') + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ';' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%myColumn%";` then `exec sp_executesql @myTables;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a kinda of some complicated logic so you probably have to take a look at a cursors. In that case you may take a chance to operate each table name separately:

```
declare 
    cr cursor local for 
      select table_name 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t;
declare @tName nvarchar(128);
open cr;
fetch next from cr into @tName ;
while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
begin
  print @tName;
  // do whatever you need here
  fetch next from cr into @tName ;
end;
close cr;
deallocate cr;
```

Here is a full description of its functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/cursors-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM '+ TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%myColumn%'
```

This Query will return all select Queries you are expecting.

if you want to get the result of those select query:

```
    DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @SQLQuery = COALESCE(@SQLQuery,'')+'SELECT * FROM '+ TABLE_NAME+';'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%myColumn%'

    SELECT @SQLQuery

    EXEC (@SQLQuery)
```